# Bugtracking on userlevel

Tags: php

I'm starting up an new project (php) where we expect at lot of users. Often people send in an email if they find some bugs, or they write in a specific page for this.

But is it possible in some way to automatically let our developers know (either through mail or a small custom app), when a user cant get something to work or hit an 404 page, where it went wrong and what equipment (browser and platform) the user used?

If so we could look at a list and quickly find the most problematic areas of our site and fix those problems before our users gets so annoyed that they will write to us.

Comment: you can handle 404,500 etc errors with htaccess in php

Comment: If you are expecting a lot of users, I guess you will use a framework for PHP. And those frameworks always log 403, 404, 500, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do this.There are many ways but i am showing you a very simple way to do this,

You need to create a Custom Error custom error handler . In that, you can handle all the errors and include them in email and log

[See For details](http://phpmaster.com/error-handling-in-php/)

```
<?php
    function errorHandler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline) {
        static $db;
        if (empty($db)) {
            $db = new PDO(DSN, DBUSER, DBPASS);
        }

        $query = "INSERT INTO errorlog (severity, message, filename, lineno, time) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, NOW())";
        $stmt = $db->prepare($query);

        switch ($errno) {
            case E_NOTICE:
            case E_USER_NOTICE:
            case E_DEPRECATED:
            case E_USER_DEPRECATED:
            case E_STRICT:
                $stmt->execute(array("NOTICE", $errstr, $errfile, $errline));
                break;

            case E_WARNING:
            case E_USER_WARNING:
                $stmt->execute(array("WARNING", $errstr, $errfile, $errline));
                break;

            case E_ERROR:
            case E_USER_ERROR:
                $stmt->execute(array("FATAL", $errstr, $errfile, $errline));
                exit("FATAL error $errstr at $errfile:$errline");

            default:
                exit("Unknown error at $errfile:$errline");
        }
    }

    set_error_handler("errorHandler");

    $test = 5;
    if ($test > 1) {
       trigger_error("Value of \$test must be 1 or less", E_USER_NOTICE);
    }
```

You can do whatever want here. Either Email or Log event :)

Comment: Hi all just found this: Getsentry.com. It seems it can do what I want. Anyone who has experience with it?